# PayPal 10413 error on when subtotal of order is 0

Tags: magento, paypal, magento2, express-checkout, magento-2.3

We are using PayPal express checkout in our Magento 2.3.2 store.

When ever we apply promotion so that the subtotal becomes 0 and grand total include only shipping price and tax amount (i.e. the product is free of cost after the promotion is applied but user have to pay tax and shipping amount), transaction is rejected by PayPal and we see "10413: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details" message on checkout page.

I looked into the data that is being sent in the API, and found out that there is no mismatch in the data.

We tried setting 'send line item configuration' to No (which is the common suggested answer to PayPal 10413 issue), but it didn't help us.

**below is the log of request and the response from PayPal.**

```
'request' =>
  array (
    'user' => '****',
    'vendor' => 'SPAPayPalGateway',
    'partner' => 'Paypal',
    'pwd' => '****',
    'verbosity' => 'HIGH',
    'BUTTONSOURCE' => 'Magento_Cart_Enterprise',
    'tender' => 'C',
    'custref' => '301000004838',
    'invnum' => '301000004838',
    'comment1' => '301000004838',
    'firstname' => 'Priyambad',
    'lastname' => 'Pandey',
    'street' => 'st',
    'city' => 'New York',
    'state' => 'CA',
    'zip' => '90001',
    'country' => 'US',
    'email' => 'priyambadp@cybage.com',
    'shiptofirstname' => 'Priyambad',
    'shiptolastname' => 'Pandey',
    'shiptostreet' => 'st',
    'shiptocity' => 'New York',
    'shiptostate' => 'CA',
    'shiptozip' => '90001',
    'shiptocountry' => 'US',
    'trxtype' => 'A',
    'origid' => 'B40P0BDC1E1A',
    'amt' => '9.67',
    'currency' => 'USD',
    'taxamt' => '0.00',
    'freightamt' => '9.67',
  )

  'result' =>
  array (
    'result' => '7',
    'pnref' => 'B70PAD120470',
    'respmsg' => 'Field format error: 10413-The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts.',
    'hostcode' => '10413',
    'transtime' => '2020-02-05 05:24:32',
    'firstname' => 'Priyambad',
    'lastname' => 'Pandey',
    'amt' => '9.67',
    'acct' => '****',
    'expdate' => '****',
    'cardtype' => '0',
    'result_code' => '7',
  )
```

Comment: Unless you log the SetExpressCheckout request and post it here, it will be hard for us to determine what exactly is causing the problem. It may simply be that the API will not accept a 0 in that field.

Comment: @PrestonPHX I have updated my question. Please have a look.

Comment: I would try initializing the array with an `'itemamt' => '0.00'`, so that one is passed if not overwridden

Comment: @PrestonPHX, this request is what Magento sends to paypal by default, we have not done any customization in this. Do I need to add 'itemamt' attribute in the request ?

Comment: That is the first thing I would try.

Comment: @PrestonPHX, I have added 'itemamt' => '0.00', field in the request, still payment is getting rejected, getting same error.